# Use C# DLL in VBA

Tags: c#, vba, dll, google-drive-api, class-library

I have a class library written in C# that uses the google drive v3 API to keep a local file repository updated. This code works perfectly fine in a console application, however when I add a reference in the VBA tools to this DLL after applying the necessary measures (registering it etc), it does not run the updateFiles Method in VBA. It does however run other functions that do not depend on the google drive API. My question is, how can I get this dll working in VBA. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks in advance

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace fileUpdater
{
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Class1
    {
        private static DriveService service;
        private static Dictionary<string, Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = new Dictionary<string, Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File>();
        private const string FOLDER_MIME_TYPE = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
        private static double percentComplete;

        private string AbsPath(Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file)
        {
            var name = file.Name;

            if (file.Parents.Count() == 0)
            {
                return name;
            }

            var path = new List<string>();

            while (true)
            {
                var parent = GetParent(file.Parents[0]);

                if (parent.Parents == null || parent.Parents.Count() == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                path.Insert(0, parent.Name);
                file = parent;
            }
            path.Add(name);
            return path.Aggregate((current, next) => Path.Combine(current, next));
        }

        private Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File GetParent(string id)
        {
            if (files.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                return files[id];
            }

            var request = service.Files.Get(id);
            request.Fields = "name,parents";
            var parent = request.Execute();

            files[id] = parent;

            return parent;
        }

        public void updateFiles()
        {
            service = AuthenticateServiceAccount("serviceAccountEmail", @"serviceAccountCredentials");
            if (service == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
            listRequest.Fields = "files(id, name, mimeType, parents, createdTime)";
            listRequest.PageSize = 1000;
            IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
                .Files;
            double counter = 0.0f;
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                percentComplete = Math.Round((counter / files.Count) * 100, 2);
                if (file.Parents != null)
                {
                    string path = "downloadFile/" + AbsPath(file);
                    if (file.MimeType == FOLDER_MIME_TYPE)
                    {
                        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
                        {
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                        {
                            if (DateTime.Compare((DateTime)file.CreatedTime, System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(path)) > 0)
                            {
                                System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                                downloadFile(file, path);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            downloadFile(file, path);
                        }
                    }
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }

        private void downloadFile(Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file, string path)
        {
            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

            service.Files.Get(file.Id).Download(stream);
            System.IO.FileStream fileToWrite = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);

            stream.WriteTo(fileToWrite);

            fileToWrite.Close();
        }


        private DriveService AuthenticateServiceAccount(string serviceAccountEmail, string keyFilePath)
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(keyFilePath))
            {
                return null;
            }

            string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive };

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            try
            {
                ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                    {
                        Scopes = scopes
                    }.FromCertificate(certificate));
                DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample"
                });
                return service;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                return null;
            }
        }

        public double getPercentComplete()
        {
            return percentComplete;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `string path = "downloadFile/" + AbsPath(file);` is this relying on the current directory?  You probably don't want to do that.

Comment: Could you please describe the error you are getting when you say "it does not run the updateFiles Method in VBA".  Are you getting a VBA compile error?  And what VBA host are you using?  Excel, Word?

Comment: I am using Excel. Initially I had two classes in the class library, A class1 and fileUpdater class, when building the project and adding the dll as a reference in VBA, only Class1 would show with intellisense, and not fileUpdater. Class1 just had one standard add function that worked fine through VBA. However fileUpdater was not showing through intellisense and could not be used. No errors were produced, however it just wasnt showing the needed class and I couldn't instantiate it.